# Trying to import module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I am trying to import a method from another class, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Report-monitoring-system\com\acc\report\main\Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from com.acc.report.report.review.Review import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com'
```

Here's my code below. I want to access methods from Review class which is under com.acc.report.report.review.Review.py and from the class from where I am importing is under com.acc.report.main.Main.py

```
from com.acc.report.report.review.Review import *
    class Main:
    
        program = Tk()
    
        def selectReports(self):
            messagebox.showinfo("EDP", "All reports")
    
        def showReports(self):
            messagebox.showinfo("EDP", "Select reports")
    
        def Show_Page(self):
            # program = Tk()
            self.program.title("My Tkinter app")
            style = ttk.Style()
            style.map("C.TButton",
            foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
            background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'black'), ('active', 'white')]
            )
            self.program.geometry("626x431")
            reviewObj = Review()
            monitor = ttk.Button(name="",text="Monitor",command=reviewObj.reviewReport,style="C.TButton")
            monitor.pack(pady=100)
            review = ttk.Button(name="",text="Review",command=self.selectReports,style="C.TButton")
            review.pack(pady=0)
            self.program.mainloop()
        
    # Main method 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        objectMain = Main()
        objectMain.Show_Page()
```

Comment: What matters is what directory you're in when you run the app.  You might consider `import sys` / `sys.path.append("D:/Python/Report-monitoring-system")`.  That will get you rolling.

Comment: @TimRoberts this just worked. Thanks!